# Which graphs are best suited to visualize multiple pre- and post-test scores between multiple groups?

Tags: data-visualization, spss, repeated-measures

I have a relatively small sample ($N = 64$) with the following variables:

- `ScoreA_I`: continuous pre-test response variable
- `ScoreA_II`: continuous post-test response variable
- `ScoreB_I`: continuous pre-test response variable
- `ScoreB_II`: continuous post-test response variable
- `sex`: 2 level categorical predictor variable
- `location`: 2 level categorical predictor variable

I'd like to visualize differences between the different groups (sex and location) for the scores. I think I probably want one graph for `sex * ScoreA_I-II * ScoreB_I-II`, another for `location * ScoreA_I-II * ScoreB_I-II`, and another one for the combination `sex * location * Scores`. An option would be to calculate the differences of the scores and plot them with error bars. But I'd like to also show the achieved scores for each group.

What graphs are best suitable (and can be ideally done in SPSS)?

Comment: If your *only* question is how to get SPSS to do this, this Q is off-topic for CV (see our [help center](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). You might try on of the SPSS specific resources listed [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/spss/info). If you have a question about the substantive data visualization issues here, please edit to clarify; otherwise, this Q may be closed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to use SPSS.

Comment: I am really sorry! I've edited the question to make it more appropriate and posted the original one to Stackoverflow.

Comment: There's no need to apologize, this is a common misunderstanding. I was just informing you. Just FYI, you may well get the best &/or fastest answer if you try one of the SPSS specific resources listed at the link above, rather than SO.

Comment: Ok, you are probably right. Most questions tagged with SPSS don't have any answers ;-(

Comment: Are `ScoreA` & `ScoreB` continuous variables? Which is the response variable, `ScoreA`, `ScoreB`, or both? Am I correct that, eg, `ScoreA_I` means *before* & `ScoreA_II` means *after*?

Comment: Yes the scores are continuous variables and both are response variables. And yes, I and II indicate pre- and post-test.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The scores are discrete. They have been calculated from a 6 point scale questionnaire.

Comment: @gung Thanks for editing my question, but it's not correct that the score variables are 6-point. They are the sums of all 6-point scale questions. The ranges of of *ScoreA* and "ScoreB" are similar.

Comment: If they are computed from a set of likert items that measure the same construct, you can generally treat them as continuous. Do you think of these as continuous?

Comment: First I thought they are continuous but per definition they are discrete IMHO. I don't think it makes a difference here.

Comment: *An option would be to calculate the differences of the scores and plot them with error bars. But I'd like to also show the achieved scores for each group.* In the same plot?

Comment: I don't think it possible or practical to combine everything. For the differences a separate plot should suffice.